# How to translate a block automatically created with a view?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

Displaying only the block translated into Italian language change when I see the same block in Italian.
I send you a picture of my view...
[image]

Comment: I am a little confused with your description. Please clarify what you are trying to do and under what conditions.